# Margin space same color as element content background in <td>

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I am designing a mail in Mailchimp and want two buttons on side by side. Therefore I inserted a code block and copied the regular button element in it, then copied the td tag and pasted it below the first td tag. Then I put "margin-left: 80px" in the style of the second button to get space in between (after trying align left and right but this did not work).

I expected two buttons with a white (body background) space in between but the space in between the buttons is the same color as the buttons itself.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-collapse: separate !important;border-radius: 3px;background-color: #F59B29;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;padding: 15px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
              <a class="mcnButton " title="More information" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">More information</a>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;padding: 15px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
              <a class="mcnButton " title="More information" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;margin-left: 80px;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">More information</a>

          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anybody know why the margin space is not the background color?

Comment: Because it represents the space outside of the box-model - use `padding` instead of `margin`.

Comment: I've read that indeed and forgot to say I tried it too but still shows the element content color and the space in between is clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way to do it.You had a missing closing td after the first anchor tag.

- I removed the background color from the table and added it to the td's
- removed the margin-left of 80px from the anchor tag
- moved the border radius to the td's

You can change the width of the blank td i placed to whatever you want it to be.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-collapse: separate !important;border-radius: 3px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;padding: 15px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #F59B29;border-radius: 3px;">
              <a class="mcnButton " title="More information" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">More information</a></td>
          <td width="20"></td><!-- to create space -->
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;padding: 15px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #F59B29;border-radius: 3px;">
              <a class="mcnButton " title="More information" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;display: block;">More information</a>

          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.. Hope this help and if you want more customization you can add own..
Try this:

```html
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-collapse: separate !important;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; width:550px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;padding: 15px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; width:100%">
                        <a class="mcnButton " title="More information" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="background-color: #F59B29;border-radius:3px;font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;width:45%; padding:8px 10px;display: block; float:left;">More information</a>
                        <a class="mcnButton " title="More information" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="background-color: #F59B29;border-radius:3px; font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;margin-left:10px;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;padding:8px 10px;display: block; width:45%; float:left;">More information</a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this, you should use padding instead of margin

Comment: padding will not work as there are two td's right beside each other.